# What was the RTL version number in Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I presuppose it was 21.0, can someone confirm this assumption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 21 is D2010. D2009 was version 20.

Comment: I would add the note about `RTLVersion` constant where you can find it. +1 anyway

Comment: Just for future reference (to @az01): RTLVersion is always defined in System.pas, almost immediately after the `interface` keyword, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

A complete list of RTLversion, compiler versions and Delphi version can be found in jedi.inc from de jedi project.

See here for details: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Help:Jedi.inc

This line specifies the RTL version:

> RTL200_UP  Defined when compiling with Delphi or C++Builder Personalities of BDS 6.0 or higher

`BDS 6.0` being Delphi 2009.